# If text inside <p> is X then addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check what is the content in the nearest `<p>` and add a Class to a div accordingly.

Here's where I'm stuck.

```js
$('p').each(function () {
    if ($('p').text() == 'E. A. K') {
        $('.pl1').addClass('service');
    }else{
        $('.pl2').addClass('service');
    }
});
```

```css
.service:after{content:"(service)"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>E. A. K.</p>
<p>F. F.</p>

<span class=pl1>Player 1</span><br>
<span class=pl2>Player 2</span>
```

SO 
if the first `<p>` is E. A. K. then `.pl1` has class `service`
if the first `<p>` is F. F. then `.pl2` has class `service`

Consider that there are many `<p>` all with those two contents.
And some new will be added from time to time.

Comment: Whats your problem? And by the way why classes in spans are not in "" quotes?

Comment: Well `E. A. K` != `E. A. K.` (note the period at the end).

Comment: Federico, Let's assume we fix the problem with your if else statement, because it's wrong. in this case both pl1 and pl2 with get the class service. so what is supposed to happen?... Also you say `nearest <p>` nearest to what???

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen 
if <p> is E . A . K then .pl1 has class service
if <p> is F. F. then .pl2 has class service

Comment: Please explain what you mean by **`the nearest <p>`**, at the moment you are just looping over all `<p>` and the concept of near-ness (near to what?) isn't present anywhere in the code.

Comment: @PeterB the <p> that appears closest to the top of the body, let's say?

Comment: @Federico As i said, the logic makes no sense, since you loop through each p, aka 2 times. in this case 1 time it ture and one time it's not. So both pl1 and pl2 will get the class

Comment: @Federico You have common coding syntax issue like unnecessary/ un-closed brackets. Now run your edited question and let us know if your problem still persist. If persist, then explain what problem you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to speed down things a bit, and make sure you close your brackets the correct places.

You say `the <p> that appears closest to the top of the body`, then you only want 1, so there is no need to loop through each `<p>`

This should do what you want, but still unsure since your logic is kinda strange, anyway hope it helps.

```
$('body p:first').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'E. A. K.') {
    $('.pl1').addClass('service');
  } else {
    $('.pl2').addClass('service');
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('body p:first').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'E. A. K.') {
    $('.pl1').addClass('service');
  } else {
    $('.pl2').addClass('service');
  }
});
```

```css
.service:after {
  content: "(service)"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>E. A. K.</p>
<p>F. F.</p>

<span class=pl1>Player 1</span><br>
<span class=pl2>Player 2</span>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much!
If I'll add a new p will this function keep checking what's the content of 'body p:first' right?

Comment: Yes, this will only look at the first p in your body

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Federico No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('p:first').map(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "E. A. K.") {
    $('.pl1').addClass('service');
  } else {
    $('.pl2').addClass('service');
  }
});
```

```css
.service {
  color: red;
}

.service:after {
  content: "(service)"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>E. A. K.</p>
<p>F. F.</p>

<span class="pl1">Player 1</span><br>
<span class="pl2">Player 2</span>
```